# Object в ArrayList / Error

Tags: java

При компиляции след. кода возникает ошибка:

> incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to ArrayList.

Главный класс:

```
public class Save extends Animal{

   public static void main(String[] args){

       Animal cat = new Animal();

       WildParkController.addAnimal( cat );

   }

}
```

Контроллер:

```
import java.util.*;

public class WildParkController  {

    private static ArrayList<Animal> AnimalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();

    public static ArrayList addAnimal(Animal animal){
        return AnimalList.add(animal);
    }

}
```

Класс `Animal`:

```
public  class Animal{

    public static String name = "cat";
    public static int ADULT_WEIGHT = 10;
    public static boolean isFeedingNewborns = true;
    public static float ENERGETIC_EFFICIENCY_PER_KILO = 3;

}
```

Объясните почему так происходит. Как можно записать объект в `ArrayList`, если это возможно?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в методе `addAnimal`:

> ```
> public static ArrayList addAnimal(Animal animal){
>     return AnimalList.add(animal);
> }
> ```

Тип возвращаемого значения этого метода — [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). А в коде возвращается результат вызова метода [`ArrayList::add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-), который возвращает `true`, если коллекция изменилась в результате вызова.

Можно сделать чтобы метод ничего не возвращал (изменить тип возвращаемого значения на [`void`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void)):

```
public static void addAnimal(Animal animal){
    AnimalList.add(animal);
}
```

Либо сделать чтобы метод возвращал экземпляр класса на котором был вызван (это называется [текущий интерфейс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)) (конечно, в этом случае метод должен быть нестатическим):

```
public WildParkController addAnimal(Animal animal){
    AnimalList.add(animal);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Второй способ не работает. Выдаёт ошибку:
    error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            return this;

Comment: @Дима а ну да, это же статический метод, так что второй способ подходит только для нестатических методов

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать экземпляр класса WildParkController.
И тогда вы сможете вызвать метод вашего объекта:
   controller.addAnimal( cat );

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class WildParkController {
     private static ArrayList<Animal> AnimalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();

   /* public static ArrayList addAnimal(Animal animal){
        return AnimalList.add(animal);
    }*/
    public  void addAnimal(Animal animal){
    AnimalList.add(animal);
    }
}
```

Save:

```
public class Save extends Animal{
    public static void main(String[] args){

       Animal cat = new Animal();
       WildParkController  controller = new WildParkController();
       controller.addAnimal( cat );

   }
}
```

Comment: AnimalList лучше назвать animalList.  Имена объектов с маленькой буквы, имена классов с большой.